# Automate default settings through Android app

Tags: android, automation

How can automate below mentioned manual setup?

I want to create android app that make below setup automatically, when i click on launching icon(every time when launch app).

**a. Enable GPS Satellite**

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to “Location Services”
3. Make sure that “use wireless networks”  is not ticked.
4. Make sure that “use GPS satellites” is ticked.
5. Make sure that “Location and Google Search” is ticked.

**b. Change “Google Settings”.**

1. Come to main screen of Tab.
2. search for “Google Settings”
3. Go to “Location”
4. Make sure that “Access location” is ticked.

**c. Enable Location  in browser settings.**

1. Make sure you are on main screen of Tablet.
2. Click on Internet Browser
3. Make sure browser is open (in many case login screen of “Renaissance” will come).
4. Click on Menu button of tablet. (one of the 3 buttons  on tablet. Left of middle button
5. Make sure a menu list is open.
6. Click on settings (last option of menu). This will open the settings screen of browser.
7. Click on Privacy and Security section
8. Click on “Clear Catch”, “Clear History”, “Clear All Cookie data”, “Clear form data” & “Clear location access”
9. Make sure that  “Turn on Location” option is Tick.

**d. Clear junk browser data**

1. Make sure you are on main screen of Tablet.
2. Click on settings
3. Go to “Application Manager”
4. From the list of application displayed on Right Side of screen, select Chrome.
5. Now you will find 3 options  here:
   Force Stop
   Uninstall Updates 
   Clear data
6. Click on “Clear data”
7. Click on “Clear Catch”.

   - Please suggest needful.

Comment: Friend!! Please give reason to downvote question.. I have to complete this task anyway..

Comment: -1 Not by me, But I guess the reason is you havent shown us, what you have code uptil now. We are not here to complete your task list.

Comment: Yeah , you are right , i am not telling to complete task. just need possible suggestion. i have no clue that's why...

Comment: Then better first google it. Try some code your self and then ask question with code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . But m googling for last 2 hours . After feel helpless. i put my question here. and still googling

Answer (score 1):

You can't develop application like that. Those settings are too sensitive to allow application manipulate with them. All you can do is just check if some provider is turned on/off and navigate user to manually change it. You have to do it manually.